# How to run tests with a WebApplicationFactory when Main is using app.Run() with url argument without "no valid IServerAddressesFeature" exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I've created tests for my services using xUnit using a WebApplicationFactory in dotnet 6.0, which has worked perfectly to test the controllers, but when I started sending in the url as an argument with `app.Run` the tests won't run anymore. Now I get the following exception thrown in Program.cs/Main on the app.Run-line when trying to run my tests:

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Changing the URL is not supported because no valid IServerAddressesFeature was found.'`

With this stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.Listen(String url)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.Run(String url)
   at ServiceName.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\../repos\SolutionName\ServiceName\Program.cs:line 24
```

This is my test code:

```
public class ServiceController_should
    : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>, IDisposable
{

    private HttpClient _client;

    public ServiceController_should(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _client = factory
            .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
            {
                builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    //configure DI services
                });
            }
            )
            .CreateClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
    ...
```

Here's my service main where the exception is thrown when running the tests:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        var startup = new Startup(builder.Configuration);
        startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

        var app = builder.Build();

        startup.Configure(app);

        app.Run("http://+:5202");
    }
```

I've googled for the exception and didn't find much. The best I've found is [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39777) where they say to add a mock to TestServer.Features.
Another relevant is this https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38185, where it says the bug is resolved, but I still get the exception.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Could you share your dotnet version and the environment?

Comment: Of course: 
I'm running dotnet 6.0 in Windows 10. 
I'm considering trying with dotnet 7.
Thank you for any input

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in .Net 6 `WebApplicationFactory` that is already fixed in later versions.

Instead of using `UseUrls()` or `app.Run("localhost:8080")` use following code in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
    serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(8080);
});
```